# How to make a program to restart itself? (Linux process)

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system

I'm trying to get my program to restart itself, but nothing seems to work. I tried using `fork()`, but after killing *the* `parent` process *the* `child` gets killed too.

**CODE**

```
void sigup_handler(int signum) {
    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        execve("prog2", NULL); 
    }
    else
        kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
}

int main() {
    puts("Program 2 started.");
    signal(SIGHUP, sigup_handler);
    sleep(50); 
    puts("Program 2 terminated.");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why bother with the `fork` if you're just going to `kill` *the* `parent`? Just do the `exec`. The new instance of the program will still be the same process but will effectively be rebooted.

Comment: It outputs Program 2 started. Program 2 started. with simple  execve("prog2", NULL); This confused me. Shouldn't it display "Program 2 terminated."?

Comment: It will never call "Program 2 terminated" because the parent has already terminated itself with kill(getpid(),...);

Comment: Ok, then. Anyway this message is easily achievable by placing it in the places where one process is guaranteed to terminate.

Comment: Note that file descriptors of the old process image will remain open!

Answer (score 5):

Use 2 levels of forking. A parent "monitor" app which forks off children and monitors their status. If a child dies, the monitor starts up a new one. The children then do their own forking to do whatever it is they have to do.

However, if you don't need the 'new' copy of the app to have the same state as the one that's being killed, then using exec() to start a fresh independent copy is likely a better option, saving you having to have that monitor copy sitting around.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) followed by [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: Would you mind giving simple code to demonstrate the use?

Comment: That what I did of course, without much success: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51654668/1098603